# Gettnig Maximum value from the nsdictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

here is my code ,
 NSMutableDictionary *dictstud1marks = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

```
[dictstud1marks setObject:@40 forKey:@"Maths"];
[dictstud1marks setObject:@50 forKey:@"English"];
[dictstud1marks setObject:@60 forKey:@"Science"];

NSMutableDictionary *dictstud2marks = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[dictstud2marks setObject:@50 forKey:@"Maths"];
[dictstud2marks setObject:@60 forKey:@"English"];
[dictstud2marks setObject:@80 forKey:@"Science"];


NSMutableDictionary *dictstud3marks = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[dictstud3marks setObject:@70 forKey:@"Maths"];
[dictstud3marks setObject:@80 forKey:@"English"];
[dictstud3marks setObject:@90 forKey:@"Science"];


NSMutableDictionary *dictstud =[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[dictstud setObject:dictstud1marks forKey:@"Ram"];
[dictstud setObject:dictstud2marks forKey:@"Rohit"];
[dictstud setObject:dictstud3marks forKey:@"Saraf"];
```

I want to know how to get the maximum values from this dictionary .please help me to solve .
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Which dictionary; there are 4?

Comment: These are NSMutableDictionary ,it is nested nsdictionary i want maximum values in all the dictionary

Comment: There are 4 NSMutableDictionary from which you want maximum values?

Comment: I want maximum values from *dictstud  ,this stores other 3 nsmutabledictionaries

Comment: I want maximum values from *dictstud nsmutabledictionary ....

Comment: OK, so what have you tried?  Looks fairly trivial.

Comment: you want maximum from total of 3 subject for particular student?

Comment: Thanks for replying Viraj Padsala,ya i want maximum value from the total of 3 subject for particular student only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary  *maximumDictFinal= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSString  *marks;
NSArray *temp = [dictstud allKeys];
for (int i=0 ; i<[temp count]; i++) {
    NSMutableDictionary *maximumDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    NSArray *blockSortedKeys = [[dictstud objectForKey:[temp objectAtIndex:i]] keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
        // Switching the order of the operands reverses the sort direction
        return [obj2 compare:obj1];
    }];
     marks =  [[[dictstud objectForKey:[temp objectAtIndex:i]]allValues] valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"];
    [maximumDict setObject:marks  forKey:[blockSortedKeys objectAtIndex:0]];
    [maximumDictFinal setObject:maximumDict forKey:[temp objectAtIndex:i]];

       }
NSLog(@"maximumDict..%@",maximumDictFinal);
```

As per Your comment

```
    int maximum =0;
int prevMaximum ;
for (NSDictionary *dict in dictstud)
{

   prevMaximum =[[[[dictstud objectForKey:dict]allValues] valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"] intValue];
    if (prevMaximum >maximum) {
        maximum =prevMaximum;

    }

}
 NSLog(@"maximum marks of student ..%d",maximum);
```

Comment: what u did is correct thanks ,but i want the result as 90 now please tell me

Comment: Thanks for sandy ,for helping this much .

Answer (score 0):

Trying sandy's answer in a loop will provide your expected result.

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in dictstud)
{
          NSLog(@"maximum marks of student ..%@",[[[dictstud objectForKey:dict]allValues] valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this once:

```
NSLog(@"maximum marks of student ..%@",[[[dictstud objectForKey:@"Saraf"]allValues] valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"]);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying sandy

Comment: ya i want maximum value from the total of 3 subject for particular student only .as per above comment i have done. is this fine?

Comment: But, i want to iterate the all dictionary and want to get the maximum values from the nested nsdictionary

Comment: Hi ,i placed a scrollview in storyboard ,then i add five ui view to that scrollview programmatically and then i enabled paging in storyboard ,now i want to scroll the uiview horizontally... please say how to do ..